# Creación de metodo para graficas Chart c#

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día, actualmente estoy construyendo dashboards que se conectan a bases de datos SQL SERVER, y a su vez, me gustaría ya todo se hiciera desde un método previamente cargado. Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma, pero me manda errores.

```
//genera graficos
public void Genera_grafico_barra(string Id_grafico, string Titulo_grafico, string nombre_Series_grafico, string nombre_Chart_Area_grafico, string columna_1, string columna_2)
{

    public Random rnd = new Random();

    Id_grafico.Titles.Add(Titulo_grafico).Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    Id_grafico.ChartAreas[nombre_Chart_Area_grafico].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Id_grafico.ChartAreas[nombre_Chart_Area_grafico].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;


    Id_grafico.Series[nombre_Series_grafico].Points.AddXY(row[columna_1], row[columna_2]);
    Id_grafico.Series[nombre_Series_grafico].Tooltip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";
    Id_grafico.Series[nombre_Series_grafico].Label =  "#VALY\n";
    Id_grafico.Series[nombre_Series_grafico].SmartLabelStyle.Enable = true;

    Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));

    Id_grafico.Series[nombre_series_grafico].Points[n].Color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));       
}
```

Esto es el código que estoy utilizando de manera manual para ir generando mis graficos.

```
protected void ObtenerDatos(string strmes)

    {

        DataSet resultado = new DataSet();            

        clsConexioncs conexion_server = new clsConexioncs();

        conexion_server.Conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultDW"].ToString();           


        //conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_telemtria_femsa");
        conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_femsa_telemetria_mensual");

        conexion_server.AgregarParametro("Mes", SqlDbType.VarChar, strmes);


        resultado = conexion_server.EjecutaComandoDataSet();


        Graficas_Semanal.Titles.Add("No. Camiones Promedio Mes Actual").Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
        Graficas_Semanal.ChartAreas["ChartArea"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Graficas_Semanal.ChartAreas["ChartArea"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

        Grafica_Dona.Titles.Add("Mes Actual").Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);


        /*
        Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.AddXY("Mongue", 125);*/


        int n = 0;           

        foreach (DataRow row in resultado.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            //Graficas_Semanal.Series.Add("Series" + resultado.Tables[0].Rows.ToString());

            //Graficas_Semanal.Series.Add("ChartArea" + resultado.Tables[0].Rows.ToString());

            //Graficas_Semanal.Series[resultado.Tables[0].Rows.ToString()].ChartArea = "ChartArea" + resultado.Tables[0].Rows.ToString();                

            //System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));                                

            Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.AddXY(row["CeEmplazamiento"], row["Totales"]);

            Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].ToolTip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";

            Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Label = "#VALY\n";

            Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;



            Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));

            Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points[n].Color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));

            n++;                





            Grafica_Dona.Series["Series_Dona"].Points.AddXY(row["CeEmplazamiento"], row["Totales"]);

            Grafica_Dona.Series["Series_Dona"].ToolTip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";

            Grafica_Dona.Series["Series_Dona"].Label = "#VALY\n #VALX";

            Grafica_Dona.Series["Series_Dona"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;


        }

        //Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.DataBindXY(resultado.Tables[0],RowNotInTableException[);
        //Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.AddXY(nombs, barras);

    }
```

¿Alguien ha hecho un método parececido? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Muestra algún error? ¿Cuál es el resultado obtenido? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?... ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Porque dudo que sea si alguien hizo algo parecido, cuya respuesta sería sí/no... En todas las preguntas intenta incluir un [mcve] y asegurarte de [qué preguntas evitar](/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Que tal a todos, una disculpa por no contestarles. Estuve investigando,la mayor parte del error que no me permitía recuperar el método, equivalia a que, debe de utilizarse la libreria:  using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;...               Por lo tanto no me reconocia los objetos.